# Magento 1.9 AW blog error when generating sitemap

Tags: xml, magento-1.9, blogs

I am getting an error with AW Blog when generating Google sitemaps from my Magento 1.9.2.4 website. The error is as follows `Fatal error: Call to a member function streamWrite() on a non-object in /app/code/community/AW/Blog/Model/Sitemap.php on line 129` I searched online but never found a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it happens due missing write permissions for target folder. Go to your Google Sitemap in Magento admin, check your sitemap paths and make sure they are writeable

Comment: You are correct about the permissions though i already had them set correctly. It seems that i cannot generate the xml when the dashboard is in incognito mode.

Comment: i guess you should look into this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3720/long-running-admin-page-requests-blocking-other-requests and consider to speed up your magento instance with redis (if not already done)